# Sort by a column that has AM PM type time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I have a table which has a column that the name is `ApTime` and datatype is `TIME` which stores the time in 24 hour format.

When get the data from the table, they must be shown in AM/PM format.

What I want is I want to sort the the result by `ApTime` column. What is tried was not gave me the answer I want.

Here is my code.

```
SELECT ApId,Name,EmpName,CONVERT(VARCHAR,ApTime,100)AS InTime
FROM AppDetails
ORDER BY EmpName,InTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort by `ApTime`, why are you including `EmpName` in the `order by`?  Also, you should always include a length when specifying `varchar()`:

```
SELECT ApId,Name, EmpName, CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), ApTime, 100) AS InTime
FROM AppDetails
ORDER BY InTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the result sorted by `InTime`, don't sort by `EmpName`. Additionally, if you want to sort by the time value of ApTime, just use it instead of sorting by some varchar formatting, which will sort **lexicographically**:

```
SELECT   ApId, Name, EmpName, CONVERT(VARCHAR,ApTime,100) AS InTime
FROM     AppDetails
ORDER BY ApTime;
```